# Using SAXBuilder With a Proxy URL

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, proxy

How does one handle parsing an XML file that is stored behind a proxy server? I have the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;

public class FileParsing {
    public static void parseXMLFile(String xmlFilePath) throws IOException, JDOMException {
            URL xmlFileURL = new URL(xmlFilePath);
            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            Document xmlDoc = builder.build(xmlFileURL);

            // File parsing code...
    }
}
```

Right now I get this exception:

```
 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: https://proxyserver.com/xmlFileOfInterest.xml
```

I'm assuming this is because the file is on a proxy server. Is this the cause of my problem? And if so, what is the proper way to handle files that are on proxy servers?

Answer (score 0):

you can use apache webclient to parse it

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(xmlFilePath
                ,String.class,null);    
        client = client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit)WebClient.getConfig(client).getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();               
        policy.setProxyServer(proxyurl);
        policy.setProxyServerPort(8080);
        httpConduit.setClient(policy);

    Response r = client.post(); 
InputStream response= (InputStream)r.getEntity();
```